# AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap - Unable to cast transparent proxy

Tags: c#, appdomain, code-injection

I'm writing a .NET library to inject managed DLLs into external processes. My current approach is:

1. Use `CreateRemoteThread` to force the target process to call `LoadLibrary` on an unmanaged bootstrap DLL. From this point we're executing code in the target process.
2. My bootstrap DLL then creates an instance of the CLR and calls `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` on it, which executes a method in a managed helper DLL.
3. This method creates a new AppDomain and calls `AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` to pass execution into my payload DLL, casting the result as an `IInjectionPayload`.
4. The idea is that my payload DLL exposes a class which implements `IInjectionPayload`, so the helper DLL can simply call `payload.Run()`.

I'm doing it this way so that the payload code can be completely unloaded by simply calling `AppDomain.Unload` (after signalling it to clean up).

This approach works - the class in my payload DLL is getting instantiated in the target process, so code *can* be executed - but I can't cast the object returned by `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` to an `IInjectionPayload`; it throws the following exception:

> Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'blah.Blah.IInjectionPayload'.

I've tried using `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`, and `Activator.CreateInstanceFrom` followed by `Object.Unwrap`, but both of these methods also cause the same exception to be thrown.

The signature of my payload class is:

> `public class Program : MarshalByRefObject, IInjectionPayload`

I'm stumped because the payload DLL is definitely getting loaded and the class is being instantiated, as intended.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the fix for this problem here: http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/601200.aspx

It looks like a bug in the .NET framework. The solution is to add a handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` which manually loads & returns the assembly at `args.Name`. Then you can call `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` without it throwing an exception.

Comment: This just saved my butt.  My problem seems to be with loading an AppDomain assembly from a directory other than the one that the executable is running in.  The remoting object comes back fine, but when I Unwrap() it, it claims it's not the correct type.  His resolver-handler trick works wonderfully.