# Loading a dll dynamically from another solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Hello I have this code that worked to load a dll from a project in my solution. The Dll is now in another solution.

```
public void LoadCalculationExpert(string pathToExpert)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToExpert);
    var type = assembly.GetType("Expert.CalculationExpert");
    var calculationExpert = (ICalculationExpert)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    this._container.RegisterInstance(calculationExpert, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

The Dll implement an interface perfectly identical to `ICalculationExpert`. In fact I copied interface to the other solution. So I know that the cast should work because it is an object that implement the same interface.

The thing is it throws me invalid cast exception.

My guess is the interface being in another namespace screw the cast.

The `CalculationExpert` and `ICalculationExpert` is in `namespace Expert` in another solution. `ICalculationExpert` in my solution is in `namespace GSoft.Sons.Bll.ScoreExpert`

Any idea or resource I could read ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By OOP principles copying the interface over to your solution is not going to make it identical. If you have access to the dll (namespace Expert with ICalculationExpert interface) why not add dll reference in your solution by which you can implement the same interface from namespace Expert.

Comment: Alternatively have the interface in a seperate assembly and refer the dll in both the solutions and implement the interface.

Comment: That's what I usually do. Unfortunately, the code in the dll I load is secret. I give the interface to them and they implement it. Then I must load their dll with the interface. I can't know in advance what namespace their interface or class is in. The only thing I know is their interface is identical to mine.

Comment: I hope this would give a solution to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116694/invalidcastexception-of-a-activator-createinstance-object-during-an-installation

Comment: You are welcome. reference assembly loading across AppDomains by Rick Strahl http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/19/Assembly-Loading-across-AppDomains